# Surface patch - cylinder, sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show that the unit cylinder can be covered by a single surface patch,
but that the unit sphere cannot.

Any hints? I don't have any ideas...

The definition of the book of a surface patch is:

[image]

Comment: I don't know a definition of 'surface patch' that makes this true. What do you mean by that?

Comment: What's means surface patch?

Comment: I added the definition of the book of a surface patch. @MikeMiller

Comment: I added the definition of the book of a surface patch. @Irddo

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't clear, but I assume you mean that for a cylinder you can cut a piece of paper into a single shape and fold (roll) it into a cylinder, but that you cannot do that for a sphere.  [For the cylinder, the flat shape is a rectangle with two disks touching opposite sides of length equal to the circumference of each disk.]

[image]

Here's is the case for a cone:

[image]

Here's the case for a cube:

[image]

The reason for this is that the Gaussian curvature of the cylinder is zero everywhere, whereas for a sphere it is zero nowhere.

A surface of zero Gaussian curvature (such as a cone, cube, etc.) can be "cut and flattened out onto a plane" (and the converse).  A surface with non-zero Gaussian curvature (such as a sphere, or ellipsoid) cannot.

Comment: Can we justify it only using Gaussian curvature?

Comment: Again... the problem statement is a bit unclear, specifically what is meant by "cover".  But one can state definitively that you cannot "cover" a surface with non-vanishing Gaussian curvature with a patch that has zero curvature (unless of course you can deform or stretch the cover, in which case all bets are off).